# asp.net mvc core post nested object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to post a form with a model that contains a nested model.
The details of the nested model are not part of the form, so when I post it, it's empty. How can I fix that?

Example:

```
[User]
userId int;
firstName string;
lastName string;
skills List<Skill>;

[Skill]
skillId int;
description string;
```

Now I have a form where I can edit the user's first and last name.
The skills are edited on a different page.

When I load the form with the User model, the Skills object is filled.
When I post it again, the Skill object is empty.

This is understandable, since it's not part of the form, and thus not posted.

How can I fix this without having to add the Skills object to the form as well?

Comment: Why would you need the collection in an Edit POST method? And if for some reason you did, then you just call the database to get it again

Comment: `How can I fix this without having to add the Skills object to the form as well?` if you do not want the Skill object details to be set inside the form then you can have a javascript that will run on form submit and here you will manually add the Skills object details and post the form. So in any case you need the data to be part of the form data.

Comment: I do agree with @StephenMuecke